# template condition of FK value

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two models, **Item** and **Quality**. **Item** has a field named *quality* which is a FK to **Quality**.*name*. The two tables look something like this:

```
Item
-----
itemId int PK
name varchar
quality varchar FK - Quality.name

Quality
-----
qualityId int PK
name varchar
```

I'm trying to make a template that lists all **Items** that have a certain quality. This is my code in question:

```
{% for Item in items %}
   {% if Item.quality == "Common" %}
      <div id="name_{{ Item.id }}" class="itemName">{{ Item.name }}</div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know that my table contains at least one tuple with quality="Common", but I'm not getting any output.

If I try to condition any other field then it works fine (ex: `if Item.name == "exampleName"`).

How do I use an if-statement on a value from a FK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quality` is the related object, ie an instance of Quality. If you want to compare on the basis of the name, then you have to use that attribute of the instance.

(Also, please use proper cases; instances should not have capital letters.)

```
{% for item in items %}
   {% if item.quality.name == "Common" %}
      <div id="name_{{ item.id }}" class="itemName">{{ item.name }}</div>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```